# Inflate ListView with custom ArrayAdapter - onItemClick not working?

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater, onitemclicklistener

I tried almost everything for 2 days now, but can't get it to work.

From a Service (also tried Activity) I inflate a listview oncreate:

```
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview, null);

      CreateItems adapter = new CreateItems(this,R.layout.my_listview_item, rowItems);
      ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_listview);

      listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postion, long id) {              
              Log.i("", "click list");            
           } 
          });    

      mWindowManager.addView(view, mParams);
```

I also tried to start listener like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

getView() from ArrayAdapter

```
    public class CreateItems extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {

    ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ListItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_listview_item, parent, false);
    }

    final View item = convertView;

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView title = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.title);

    icon.setImageDrawable(rowItem.getImageId());
    title.setText(appLabel.get(position).toString()); 

    return convertView;
```

my_lsitview_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:minHeight="75dp"
android:clickable="false"   
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="53dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
/>
```

listview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".listview" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"   
>
```

The Listview shows corrctly. I can move it, and also the on_pressed @drawable highlight shows on list item touch. But the onItemClick does not get started.

When I setup a onClick listener in the getView() Adapter I can get the clicks, but the on_pressed highlight is not working anymore. I guess because I catch the clickevent before it reaches the listview.

```
        icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         ....
```

How can I get this working correctly?

Comment: Why are you inflating a `View` from a `Service`? `Services` shouldn't have a UI.

Comment: Please use `View` in an `Activity` since `Services` shouldn't have a UI.

Comment: I also changed the service in an activity, but the problem still exists? seems the cause is somewhere else.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are not able to see the LOG's in the console or not able to start another activity through that `onItemClick()` method?

Comment: both, onItemClick just doesnt get called